# Why doesn't my table accept these entries?

Tags: php, mysql

My application can successfully post data to a server, and have that data saved to a file - to be later read by the server. However, when trying to save the data to the database nothing happens.

```
<?php

// Create connection`
$con=mysql_connect("exemple.com","user","password");
mysql_select_db("database");

// receive data from app's http request
$name=$_POST["name"];
$people=$_POST["people"];
$club=$_POST["club"];
$day=$_POST["day"];
$sql="INSERT INTO users (name, people, club, day) VALUES ($name, $people, $club, $day)");
mysql_query($con,$sql);
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You're not escaping the data. Add an `echo $sql;` and you'll see apart of the issue, for more read about SQL injection

Comment: You actually have a *lot* of problems. To start with: you shouldn't be using `mysql_connect`, `mysql_query`, etc. See [PHP's guide to choosing a MySQL API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: I change everything to mysqli and with the answer I fixed it. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your input should be like this:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (name, people, club, day) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$people."', '".$club."', '".$day."')";
```

else u will not save the value of each variable